# file_get_contents with full url to same server very slow with php 7 as of very recently on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, file-get-contents, php-7

can it be that it is related to:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1674733

just a thought? probably not, because in the end, it actually works.

this used to be very quick, now takes like 7 seconds up to 26 seconds for a tiny image, that is stored locally as well.

"Well just change the code to no go via http" well i would prefer to not rewrite a library I am using to fix an issue that suddenly surfaced out of nowhere. If i perform the same call locally on my local dev machine it takes a splitsecond.

`myapp/public/caup_laravel/vendor/intervention/image/src/Intervention/Image/AbstractDecoder.php`

code:

```
   $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'method'=>"GET",
            'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n".
            "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2\r\n"
      )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    if ($data = @file_get_contents($url, false, $context)) { //VERY slow call
        return $this->initFromBinary($data);
    }
```

example of url is:

http://dev.causepick.org/caup_api/uploads/causes/52/cropped-436535-a42b2.jpg

access the image via browser is instant, e.g. if i type the url into the address bar

Comment: Did you try restarting like the people in that bug report?

Comment: Are other files on the same machine also slow? Can you test a DNS lookup on that server with something like `nslookup dev.causepick.org`? If the server's DNS is causing a slow lookup to that domain, it could explain the delay not seen from other computers.

Comment: i restarted the machine yes
@MichaelBerkowski it works, but following thing: if i do `ping google.com` i have to wait like 15 seconds before the first result comes. So nothing happens for like 15 seconds, then results come in with low measured response time, somehow ignoring the fact i was basically waiting in CLI for many seconds. Similar for `dev.causepick.org`

Comment: retrying a couple times, just saying:
just got
`$ ping dev.causepick.org`
`ping: unknown host dev.causepick.org` next time i try, it does work again. Then it is quick even. Try again... works, but very slow.

Comment: I'm realizing now that I was probably contending with this same bug on an Ubuntu workstation last week, where I was losing DNS every 3-4 hours.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski what did you do to fix it? restart did not help

Comment: @Toksan I have not fixed it. It's just been intermittent, usually corrected by restarting NetworkManager. Because I was working in a room with flaky wifi, I assumed that was the cause and suffered through. But my symptoms are as described in the bug report and I suspect if I was using the same machine right now I might still be seeing the problem. I haven't used it much since 3 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

I got a response by digitalocean my server provider

> We've received reports of a DNS outage affecting users that utilize
>   Google's DNS servers, which is the default on all of our images. This
>   droplet is in the affected IP range, so it is likely related to the
>   issue.
>
> Can you try using OpenDNS's servers, 208.67.222.222 and
>   208.67.220.220, as your primary or backup nameservers? This should resolve the issue you are facing. You can do this temporarily (it will
>   persist until your next reboot) by editing /etc/resolv.conf to look
>   like this:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.222  
nameserver 208.67.220.220
```

> So far everything points to this being an issue on Google's end,
>   affecting UDP-based DNS queries from our 192.241.128.0/17 range.
>   Eventually, queries can fall back to TCP, which allows them to
>   succeed, but it takes several seconds explaining the slowness you're
>   seeing. We've seen Google rate-limit or block selective IP ranges
>   before, and it was very difficult to pin down. We've already reached
>   out to Google and we are awaiting a response and resolution.

this worked

Answer (score 0):

Check your `/etc/resolv.conf` file. A delay that long sounds a lot like you've got two nameservers in there that are useless.

Comment: 8.8.8.8
and
 8.8.4.4